# Remove jquery selectable from first row and first column of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've got a classic table and I want to do selection on td elements of it except on the first column and on the first row of the table.

I've tried doing

```
 $( ".calendarione table" ).not('tr:first-child').selectable({
        filter: "td.selectable_calendar_item",
    ...
```

But it doesn't work. (This example is relative to the first row).
How can I do?

EDIT: This is the html: http://pastebin.com/VQDJhkA9
The first row represent the days of the month, clicking on them "a element" I will open close the date of all rooms (the next rows items).

The next rows represent the rooms (is an hotel rooms availability table), the first td element is the room name and the next td elements represent the status of the room on each day.

Comment: Care to add the rest of your relevant JS and HTML/CSS into a snippet? It will make it easier for people to debug and see what you're getting

Comment: I've inserted the html of the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place first row in `thead` and make `tbody` `selectable` like below. Hope this will help you.

```js
$("#selectable > tbody").selectable();
```

```css
#selectable .ui-selecting {
  background: #FECA40;
}

#selectable .ui-selected {
  background: #F39814;
  color: white;
}

#selectable {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-beta.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<table id="selectable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```